# Who would become president if the election were delayed past January 20?

Tags: united-states, election

President Trump [tweeted](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1288818160389558273) the possibility of delaying the US general elections. He doesn't have the ability to delay the election on his own. Here's what the Constitution says on the matter:

> The Times, Places and Manner of holding Elections for Senators and
> Representatives, shall be prescribed in each State by the Legislature
> thereof; but the Congress may at any time by Law make or alter such
> Regulations, except as to the Places of chusing Senators.

Imagine that the election somehow were delayed past the inauguration date. The President's term (and the term of the Vice President and the entire Cabinet) end on January 20 no matter what. Under the order of succession, the next person to become president would be the Speaker of the House. But her term *also ends in January (EDITED)*.

There are a few things I don't understand in this situation. Would California be able to hold an election even if other elections were delayed? Would the governor of California appoint a replacement (or reappoint Speaker Pelosi)? Could the House change the rules to allow the speakership to continue after the election?

Comment: Related, possibly a partial duplicate: [How would next U.S. President be determined if there was a national emergency that significantly disrupted voting in many states?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/50597/how-would-next-u-s-president-be-determined-if-there-was-a-national-emergency-th)

Comment: "But her term ends at the same time as the President and Vice President." I don't think this is true. The new House meet on the 3rd January (and a new Speaker is presumably chosen shortly thereafter).

Comment: What @owjburnham said. I don't know if it's always on the 3rd, but the new Congress starts at least a couple weeks before the new President normally does.

Comment: This is the question that people are asking everywhere, so +1.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Under the order of succession, the next person to become president would be the Speaker of the House. But her term ends at the same time as the President and Vice President.

Most of your understanding is correct, but this line is wrong, and that's where the answers you're looking for come from.

[The 20th amendment](https://constitutioncenter.org/interactive-constitution/amendment/amendment-xx) says:

> **Section 1**
> The terms of the President and the Vice President shall end at noon on the 20th day of January, and the terms of Senators and Representatives at noon on the 3d day of January, of the years in which such terms would have ended if this article had not been ratified; and the terms of their successors shall then begin.
>
> **Section 2**
> The Congress shall assemble at least once in every year, and such meeting shall begin at noon on the 3d day of January, unless they shall by law appoint a different day.

These sections mean that the new Congress takes office 17 days before the President leaves office.  Thus, by the time the presidency was vacated and needed to follow the line of succession, there would be a Speaker of the [new] House to take the role.  Presumably, if Democrats keep the majority, this would be Speaker Pelosi.  But if she stepped aside or was replaced (by either a Republican majority or by the Democratic Representatives choosing someone else) then whoever that was would take office.

Admittedly, if the election isn't held, there is some question about who would *comprise* the new Congress.  The old Congress' term definitively ends on the 3rd, and every Representative has to be reelected every two years. So if no elections are held, then there are no Representatives (and only 2/3 of the Senators).  And unlike Senators, there is no process for a state to appoint a replacement if the office is vacated.  There can be elections to fill the empty seat, but only once it's actually empty, so they couldn't be held until the 3rd.  (Although knowing that it's coming, a state's Governor could say "get ready for elections on the 3rd", but not officially issue the writ for the election until then.)

So whichever states held their emergency elections in time would send the Representatives who would choose the Speaker who (in turn, on the 20th) would act as President.

Comment: Something notable is that the Speaker does not have to be an actual member of Congress, apparently.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - You're not wrong, but [there are definitely challenges](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/2091/2130) with trying to do that.

Comment: No, not really. It jumped out at me reading the answer, and they also discussed it in the comments - the Speaker would, surely, be considered an "elected officer."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - Hmm.  Good point - if they really wanted to do that, they'd find a way. I'm sure SCOTUS would have to weigh in before it was settled, though, even if that was just refusing to hear it because it's an internal House matter.

Comment: States don't get the choose the date of elections for President, Representatives, or Senators. Those are set by Federal statute: [2 USC §7](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/7) sets the date for Represenatives, [2 USC §1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/1) says Senators are elected at the same time as Representatives, [3 USC §1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/1) sets the date for electors for President (its the same day as  2 USC §7). States do not have the power to override those dates.

Comment: @asgallant You’re right, I missed that. On the other hand, that just falls into the “becomes vacant” clause, so there could be state-run elections at any time after the 3rd to fill those empty seats.   I’ll edit this later tonight, when I’m in front of a computer again.

Comment: I'd be foolish to try and argue that ANYTHING associated with would be easy, amiable or straightforward.

Comment: If there are no electoral college delegates elected and no votes cast, doesn't the Senate elect the president?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - No, the Senate only gets to choose between the two top candidates for VP.  If no votes are cast, there are (officially) no top candidates.  After that, the position goes to the Speaker of the House, then the President Pro Tempore of the Senate, and then down the list.

Comment: @asgallant Anyone can do anything if the appropriate deterents and punishments aren't in place. If I speed down the interstate, I'll probably get a ticket. If I speed with my pregnant wife in the car, I actually will probably not get a ticket. In fact I may just get a police escort!! While I don't support this line of logic on elections, there may well be judges who do.

Comment: I believe California will hold elections and elect Pelosi.

Comment: One thing your answer is missing is that the constitution leaves the power of when elections are held for the house and senate fully in the hands of each state. This means that the president doesn't have any control to stop those elections and it is unlikely that states will not hold those elections with how much would be on the line in the situation that the presidential and vice presidential elections did get delayed. I would guess the reason that the elections are held on the same day is for convenience and expense reasons of holding a single election day.

Comment: @JoeW Actually, that’s exactly what I had originally, but one of the earlier comments pointed out that Congress has, in fact, set the date nationally. The Constitution gives states that power, but subject to Congress’s override, which they’ve used.

Comment: Does the federal law allow a special election for the House if a seat becomes vacant? If not, then it seems like there would be no House, the state Governors would appoint Senators to fill the seats that became vacant in the Senate, and the President Pro Tem of the Senate would become President. Of course, this would all also be subject to whatever provisions Congress specified when writing the law that actually changed the election date in the first place, considering they're the only ones who can do that.

Comment: @reirab - Yeah, the Constitution requires the state's Executive to hold an election for the empty House seat.  There's no particular timeframe specified, and I don't know of Congress has weighed in on that, but the special election is required.

Comment: @Bobson Which Constitution? The state Constitution? If so, federal law supersedes it and any election held in violation of federal law would be null, regardless of what a state constitution might say.

Comment: @reirab - Assuming you're asking which Constitution requires the special election - US Constitution, Article I, Section 2, Clause 4: *When vacancies happen in the Representation from any State, the Executive Authority thereof shall issue Writs of Election to fill such Vacancies.*.  I hadn't actually realized that before writing this answer - it seems like there's usually _some_ empty seats in the House, so I just assumed that they usually stayed vacant until the next regular election.  But I hadn't really looked into it before, either.

Comment: @Bobson Ah, interesting, I had missed that paragraph. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

While I make no claim to being a Constitutional lawyer, under a simple reading of the law it seems that if elections weren't held until after January 3rd (or whenever their term ends), there would BE no House of Representatives, thus the present Speaker of the House (Pelosi) couldn't become President.

Since the Senate is a continuing body (about 1/3 of Senators being elected every two years), the president pro tempore of the Senate would become acting president.  However, no laws could be passed, since that requires a vote of both houses.  That includes appropriating money to run all government agencies. So the US government would have effectively voted itself out of existence :-)

Comment: On your last point (and I know all of this is a bit whimsical speculation, but to be pedantic), the government fiscal year is October. **IF** the current government agrees to a budget, the appropriations are there until September 30, 2021. Of course if they just agree on a short-term continuing resolution that expires on January 3 or January 20...

Comment: Note that it is unlikely that all states would delay elections until January.  Many states would still elect their members of Congress before the end of the year.

Comment: @HotLicks:  Counternote:  under the Constitution the House requires a majority of members to be present to do business, which presumably includes electing a Speaker.  So it's not necessary for *all* states to delay their elections to end up in this scenario — just a sufficiently large number of them to account for half of the representatives.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Is it a majority of the members that have been elected, or a majority of the seats that need to be filled?

Comment: @Barmar This document implies it is the majority of filled seats: https://crsreports.congress.gov/product/pdf/RL/98-988

Comment: In that case, as long as at least one state elects representatives, it should always be possible to form a quorum.

Comment: If there's no one to vote in the house, do the bills all pass with 100%? I mean, EVERY member voted in favor!! Also, no one voted in favor. Also, the vote was tied. Ugh.

Comment: @HotLicks They can't unless Congress changes the law to allow them to. The Constitution explicitly gives Congress the power to set override states on setting the times and places of elections for Congress and Congress has done so ([2 USC 7](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/7).) Any elections conducted in violation of this would be illegal and their results null. Of course, for the same reason, delaying the election in the first place would also require an act of Congress.

Comment: @corsiKa:  I suspect you were being sarcastic, but I'll answer anyway:  the question is moot, because someone has to be there to move to vote on a bill.  If there's no motion for a vote, then it's never considered.

Comment: @Barmar: I would think it would logically be the number of seats (435/2 = 218).  I'm sure that anything else would go to the Supreme Court, as would states electing Representatives if Congress postponed the election.  It'd be a mess anyway you look at it.